# Как оформить события для чата на C#?

Tags: c#, события

Хочу реализовать комнаты чата, и допустим, в комнате 5 и кто-то в комнату 5 пишет, то сгенерировать событие и переслать всем пользователям комнаты. То-есть не всем разослать, а потом проверить,если он в комнате, а рассылать непосредственно в комнату. Точнее, если юзер 1 в комнате 5, то он подписывается на событие получения нового сообщения, но только не для всех, а для комнаты 5.
Как такое реализовать?
Спасибо

Comment: А в чём конкретно проблема? Юзер подписывается на сообщения во всех комнатах, где он есть, и получает их.

Comment: @VladD как такое сделать?

Answer (score 3):

Ну вот вам примерный скелет.

У нас есть сообщение:

```
class Message
{
    // текст сообщения, дата отправления, адресат, ...
}
```

Весь чат состоит из комнат:

```
class Chat
{
    List<Room> rooms;
    public AllRooms => rooms.AsReadOnly();
    // и так далее
}
```

Комната содержит юзеров, список сообщений, и выставляет события прихода нового сообщения (а также, возможно, другие):

```
class Room
{
    List<User> users;
    List<Message> messages;

    public event EventHandler<NewMessageEventArgs> NewMessage;
    void AddMessage(message)
    {
        // проверки
        messages.Add(message);
        OnNewMessage(message);
    }

    void OnNewMessage(Message message) =>
        NewMessage?.Invoke(this, message);
}

class NewMessageEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public Message Message { get; }
    // ...
}
```

Юзеры, попадая в комнату, подписываются на приход нового сообщения:

```
class User
{
    void JoinRoom(Room room)
    {
        try
        {
            room.AddUser(this);
            // комната может и не пустить
        }
        catch (RoomException ex)
        {
            // обработать и выйти
        }
        // получить текущие сообщения...
        messages = room.GetCurrentMessages();
        // и подписаться на новые:
        room.NewMessage += OnNewMessage;
    }
}
```

Вроде бы всё?